# Tag merge for switch and ethernet-switch

Tags: support, retag-request

[switch](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/switch) (396 questions) and [ethernet-switch](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ethernet-switch) (16 questions) should be merged with [switch](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/switch) being the primary.

Comment: What if it's a FC switch, an IB switch, a voice switch etc.?

Comment: fiber-channel-switch seems like a mouthful, so I guess just 'switch' and 'fiber-channel' perhaps.  I don't know 'IB', and for voice switch, I agree you have a point, but there are 10 voice questions total on the site, so it doesn't seem to be a huge problem.

Comment: ... or a light switch?

Answer (score 4):

In order to avoid creating even more confusion in the future I suggest making `ethernet-switch` the primary, else we'll end up with:

- Inconsistency between ethernet and other switch tags.
- Ethernet questions not involving switches using a tag that people associate with switches.

Answer (score 1):

We'll want to make sure we don't create confusion with FC switches - the only question out there under [switch](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/switch) that's also under [fibre-channel](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/fibre-channel) should probably get a manual retag: [Cisco FC SAN switch decision](https://serverfault.com/questions/41262/cisco-fc-san-switch-decision)

Or should we have [ethernet-switch](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ethernet-switch) be the primary?  (I'm just throwing that out there as an idea; the line's blurring with FCoE, so my opinion is to make [switch](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/switch) the primary)